# What is Phase Space Formulation of QM and does it explain use of complex variables in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, complex-numbers, phase-space, wigner-transform

In  [arXiv:quant-ph/0504102v1](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0504102),  A.J. Bracken says

> if we think of the phase space formulation of QM as more fundamental,
>   arising directly from a deformation of classical mechanics in phase
>   space [12] we can think of the formulation of QM in Hilbert space and
>   the associated introduction of complex numbers as a computational
>   device to make calculations easier.

Reference [12] is Bayen F, Flato M, Fronsdal C, Lichnerowicz A, and 
Sterheimer, D, Annals of Physics 111 (1978) 61-110, 111-151. This seems to answer the question of why complex variables. Can anyone explain this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This paper is talking about the Wigner function, which is the Fourier transform of the density matrix $\rho(x,x')$ to be a function of $\rho(x,p)$. The density matrix formulation is arguably more fundamental, but the Wigner function is just a bad set of coordinates for the more fundamental density matrix, see my answer to this question: [an example of a quantum system for which wigner function transitions to negative values](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14906/an-example-of-a-quantum-system-for-which-wigner-function-transitions-to-negative)

The density matrix is real valued on diagonal, and only the complex parts of the matrix are off diagonal. But the mystery (if there is one) of complex numbers in quantum mechanics arises in physical circumstances, when pure states diffract. They diffract in the density matrix formulation too, because the pure states are just special density matrices. The arguments in the paper are overly formal and free of content, and this paper need not be read.

To explain further--- the formulas "28" and "34" in the paper express the complex off diagonal density matrix elements with some other notation, as the author states somewhere at the end. This paper just gives a few new symbols for old things.

#### Why QM is Complex

If you want to get rid of complex numbers in QM, take the real and imaginary parts of the wavefunction. That sounds glib, and it is: the complex nature of amplitudes means that you have states pared up in twos, $|x_r\rangle$ and $|x_i\rangle$, and these two states are indistinguishable, and if $x_r$ turns into $y_i$ with time, then $x_i$ turns into $-y_r$.

The statement that there is a complex structure to quantum mechanics is simply the statement that there is such a doubling of states. To see why this needs to be so, consider the Eigenstates of H. These have to preserve length so they must rotate into each other, so they must come in these pairs (if you insist on using real numbers, unitary time evolution has only complex eigenvalues, so you can't diagonalize it, but you can block-diagoalize it into 2 by 2 blocks, which have this doubling). Now there is a manifest symmetry of multiplying by "i" (where you introduce an operator "i" which takes the top component of each two-by-two block to the bottom component, and the bottom component to minus the top).

This works for all states except possibly the vacuum (because the vacuum has zero energy, it doesn't have to move at all under time evolution, so it doesn't need a partner). The statement is that there is always an "i" symmetry which squares to -1. This "i" commutes with almost everything else, but doesn't commute with time reversal, which switches the sign of i. This shows you that it's not really complex numbers in QM, but the "i" symmetry above, because time reversal doesn't respect i.

I believe this argument appears somewhere in the literature.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the other two answers are not satisfying from a mathematical point of view, respectively due to their brevity or dogmatic nature.  I will describe two ways in which the complex numbers are connected to the phase-space representation of quantum mechanics.

In classical mechanics, phase space is represented by a symplectic manifold.  But to make things more concrete, imagine a symplectic vector space. In finite dimensions, symplectic vector spaces over a field $\mathbb{K}$ can be regarded as vector spaces $\mathbb{K}^{2n}$ equipped with a linear map $\omega_n:\mathbb{K}^{2n}\oplus \mathbb{K}^{2n}\to \mathbb K$ such  that  $\omega_n\!\left(\begin{bmatrix} \vec p_A\\ \vec q_A\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} \vec p_B\\ \vec q_B\end{bmatrix}\right):= \vec q_A\cdot \vec p_B - \vec p_A \cdot \vec q_B$ called the symplectic form.

Taking $\mathbb{K}:=\mathbb{R}$ this grading $\mathbb{K}^{2n}\cong \mathbb{K}^{n}\oplus \mathbb{K}^{n}$ corresponds to dividing the space of possible configurations of $n$ particles into $n$ positions and $n$ momenta.  The symplectic form captures the degree of commutation determined by the positions and momenta of particles.

A state is determined by a maximally commuting subspace of a symplectic vector spaces (a Lagrangian subspace).  The unitary evolution of the state is given by linear maps which preserve the symplectic form (symplectomorphisms).  If one regards states as the equally likely possible positions and momenta, the unitary evolution corresponds to the invertible nondeterminstic evolution.

Notice already that the symplectic plane $(\mathbb{R}^2,\omega_1)$ is very similar to the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ if you regard the position basis to be the real line, and the momentum basis to be the complex line.  The transformation that takes the position basis to the momentum basis is given by the Fourier transform.  Which is conceptually, very much like the scalar $i$. For example given any rotation of the complex plane $e^{2\pi i \theta}$, there is a real symplectomorphism which rotates the real symplectic plane by $\theta$.  The complex conjugation which undoes this rotation corresponds to negating the momentum coordinates in a symplectic vector space, corresponding to the symplectomorphism $(\mathbb{R}^{2n},\omega_n)\to (\mathbb{R}^{2n},\bar\omega_n:=-\omega_n)$.

This is not where the relationship between phase space and complex numbers ends.  The attempt to take the phase-space formulation of classical mechanics and adapt it to quantum mechanics is a particular kind of quantization procedure.  To get a quantum-version of position and momentum which behaves more or less like in the classical setting, one must apply the Wigner tranformation to the quantum state.  This turns a quantum state $|\phi \rangle\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{C})$ into a quantum state $W_{|\phi \rangle}\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^{2n}, \mathbb{R})$.  So the idea is that now we have doubled the dimension of our space to account for the possible values of positions and momenta.  And we have shifted the complexity of the image of $|\phi \rangle$ to the extra dimension for momentum in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.  This is a continous and invertible transformation, but now, unlike in the classical case $W_{|\phi \rangle}$ can produce negative real numbers, so that it is not a probability.  Rather, it is a quasiprobability distribution.

In quantum computing, the more you can avoid the negativity, in general the easier the circuit is to build.  Therefore, there has been lots of interest for circuits/states whose Wigner transformations are honest probability distributions.  In finite dimensions, imposing this restriction on the discrete analogue of the Wigner representation is exactly the stabilizer/Clifford fragment of finite, odd-prime dimensional quantum mechanics. If you take the symplectic conjugate which I described earlier, this corresponds to complex conjugation in this projective representation into finite dimensional Hilbert spaces.  So here, the extra dimension for the momentum is really accounting for this complex behaviour.

In the continuous case things are more complicated, but there is conceptually still quite similar.  If you take a Lagrangian subspace of $(\mathbb{R}^{2n},\omega_n) $ and invert the Wigner transformation, you do not get a continuous map.  In order to obtain a quantum state from such a discontinuous one, one applies Gaussian convolution to smooth things out.  States obtained in this way are called coherent states, or quantum Gaussian states.  It turns out in order to add Gaussian convolution to $(\mathbb{R}^{2n},\omega_n) $, we use the complex numbers again and work with certain kinds of (positive semidefinite) Lagrangian subspaces of $(\mathbb{C}^{2n},\omega_n) $.  Here you think of the subspace $(\mathbb{C}^{2},\omega_1) $ which shears by $i$ as the vacuum state, which is the canonical Gaussian distribution on the phase space $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.  And the basic idea is that these positive complex Lagrangian subspaces correspond precisely to states which can be obtained by taking a bunch of vacuum states and then applying real symplectomorphisms to them.

One way in which you can see how this shearing by $i$ behaves the same as the Wigner representation of the vacuum is that these are in some sense uniquely determined by their property of being invariant under symplectic rotation.  We could have just as well chosen shearing by $-i$ to correspond to the vacuum, because it has this same property, but we can't have both together because it breaks the correspondance with the vacuum.

So in sum, in order to obtain a probabilistic phase-space representation of quantum mechanics... one takes the real numbers and then adds a complex dimension in two different ways.  The first corresponding to adding an extra dimension to position to obtain momentum, and the second time, you add a complex dimension in an orthogonal direction in order to represent Gaussian probability distributions on the space of positions and momentums.

We are by no means the first people to think of this, but [me and my colleagues recently wrote an article on this subject](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2403.10479.pdf) which includes various references which people might find useful.

I have necromanced this thread, but I think this needed a proper answer.  I can expand this answer further with references if anyone would find it to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The concise and intuitive answer (if you know a little bit of linear algebra) is the following: although $\mathcal H$ is a complex Hilbert space, the set of states and measurements are the Hermitian **operators** on $\mathcal H$ and these form a **real** vector space.  Most natural representations of these operators (from a linear algebra point of view) contain complex numbers (standard matrix representations, for example).  As phase space representations (and other [quasi-probability representations](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.2701)) demonstrate, this is not necessary -- the reason being already stated: the objects we are ultimately interested in for calculations are real vector spaces, not complex ones.

Comment: This is repeating the wrong point made in the paper. We are _not_ interested in representations of any algebra of operators--- the vectors themselves are physical--- you can't substitute some other representation of the same algebra, when it exists. Each representation is different. The "real vector spaces" are red herrings, the quantities involved are still complex (in real terms, the operator "i" still is in there). These arguments are sophisticated sounding but profoundly ignorant mathematical gibberish. But this mistake is the paper's: you are repeating the author's nonsense accurately.

Comment: @Ron Maimon: If you assume vectors in $\mathcal H$ are physical, then you have far bigger worries than complex numbers...

Comment: I should add that the first instance I have found of this argument is H. Jeffreys, Philosophical Magazine, Vol. 33 (1942), pp. 815-831.

Comment: they are physical in the sense that every quantity they contain can be measured in an identically prepared ensemble, and they determine the future. The issue of whether they are physical in the interpretational sense is irrelevant. Going to a density matrix does not stop there from being a pairing of states corresponding to multiplication by i, so it doesn't stop quantum mechanics from being complex, regardless of the mathematical jibberish about "real representations". A spin 1/2 and spin 1 particles are two representations of the same abstract algebra, but have different physics.